# Can't click on the "Generate Signed APK" button in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I would like to create a signed APK in Android Studio, but when I open the `Build menu` and try to click on the `Generate Signed APK` I can not do it for some reason. I am really new in Android development so I think I missed something or made a beginner mistake, but I would be really happy if somebody could tell me how can I solve the issue. As I read a `keystore` file is needed, but as I watched on Youtube tutorials the keystore file should be created after I tap the `Generate Signed APK` menu.

[image]

Comment: Are you able to run project at least once, Check the JAVA path etc

Comment: @QAMAR I just get a zip, unzipped the project file and opened in Android Studio. Where should I check the JAVA path?

Comment: did you run the program?

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the same issue previously, adding `app.iml` file resolved my issue.. With out app.iml file studio will treat the build as ant build..

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Prasad, I have the app.iml file.